# Excel addin cell functions (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, function, cell, worksheet

I'm creating an accounting add in for Microsoft Excel using Visual C#.  There are a ton of features I want to add, but many of them rely on input made dynamically by the user. I found the following code on another website using VBA:

```
 Dim jpdate

        If StrComp(comma1, "Paycheck", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           jpdate = Worksheets("Budget").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value
           'If jpdate = "" Then Exit Sub
```

The above code whenever the user presses the enter key after typing specific data typed into a specific cell.  This code can be followed up with commands to fill out the entire row, update other rows, etc.  I'm told that this data exists as worksheet-level code, but my project is an add in, NOT a workbook or template.  What I need to know is, within the context of developing add ins via Visual C#, how to invoke functions upon the user inputting data into a specific cell or range of cells.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question here... If you want to call a VBA macro from C# then use `xlApp.Run("macro_Name")`, `xlApp` being a reference to Excel.Application... If you do not want to use a VBA macro and call C# functions to populate cells you pretty much need a `Range` type variable. In VS there is intelli-sense just declare `Range myRange;` then type `myRange` and see all available funcitons ( you probably going to need `Range.get_Range` and `Range.set_Range` the most

Comment: It's pretty simple, actually.  I want to activate a function when the user types in a specified keyword into a specified cell.  How do I detect when the user enters data into a cell ON THE SPREADSHEET?

Comment: you need to work with an event in this case. Look up `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`